# Choosing which value to replace in a dictionary when replacing duplicate keys?

Tags: python

Question:
Given two dictionaries named dict1 and dict2, using "For" loop to write code to add all items of dict1 to dict2. If the key of dict1 already exists in dict2, don't add it to dict2.

for example:

```
dict1 = {1: "ab", 2: "cd"}

dict2 = {1: "ef", 3: "gh"}
```

After running your code, `dict2` should be

```
dict2 = {1: "ef", 3: "gh", 2: "cd"}
```

since the key of `1: "ab"` in `dict1` already exists in `dict2`.

My code is:

```
dict1 = {1: "ab", 2: "cd"}
dict2 = {1: "ef", 3: "gh"}
for i in [dict1]:
    if i not in [dict2]:
        dict2.update(dict1)
        print(dict2)
```

When I run it, my `dict2` is `dict2 = {1: "ab", 2: "cd", 3: "gh"}`

How do I make `dict2 = {1: "ef", 2: "cd", 3: "gh"}`

Comment: I know `dict2[1] = "ef"` can work. But it can only work for the example. I can't use this method for the real question because I don't know what dict1 and dict2 are equals to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
for i in dict1:
    if i not in dict2:
        dict2[i] = dict1[i]
#=> {1: 'ef', 2: 'cd', 3: 'gh'}
```

Comment: I tried it... python gave me an error: "type" object not subscriptable. thanks though! :)

Comment: @ProgrammingPikachu: are you sure you have not make a typo like `dict` instead of `dict1` which would explain your error?

Comment: @SergeBallesta +1 I was thinking the same thing. Forgot to mention.

Comment: @ProgrammingPikachu, you made a typo.  This is correct.

Comment: OMG HOW COULD I HAVE BEEN SO ASDFASDFASDF CARELESS!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.keys()` or `.viewkeys()` in python2 to find the different keys in `dict1` and just add those keys to your dict2:

```
dict1 = {1: "ab", 2: "cd"}

dict2 = {1: "ef", 3: "gh"}

# .viewkeys() python 2
for k in dict1.keys() - dict2:
    dict2[k] = dict1[k]

print(dict2)
{1: 'ef', 2: 'cd', 3: 'gh'}
```

Or if you prefer update:

```
dict2.update((k, dict1[k]) for k in dict1.keys() - dict2)

print(dict2) 
{1: 'ef', 2: 'cd', 3: 'gh'}
```